# How to access a webserver over 3G network?

Tags: 3g, embeddedwebserver

I have a public IP and many devices over 3G network. All the devices has a webserver running which provides status and can be controlled. They can see public IP but there is no way I can access webpages form internet. Is there any way I could relay these pages to public IP and then client could access the webpages via public IP. In another words how do I push the webpages to public IP ? Is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: This is not a software question. Investigate about NAT and routers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree, that this is not a programming question, I want to give an answer, as this might be a consideration:

3G carriers (as some others, the number likely to increase in the near future), use NAT for network access of their devices. This has the important implication of the device itself not being reachable from the outside.

For us programmers this means the breakdown of the IP end-to-end model, and our software has to take care of that. Here are some random inputs:

- Reverse server and client role: Have the device access a C&C server, instead of the other way round
- Use VPNs - maybe integrating them into your app for easier setup

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. When you say reverse server does that mean I have run a webserver on machine A which has a public IP and let embedded device and client talk to this server ? Machine A would work as a relay server between the device and client ? Does this solution exist and is it simple to configure ?

Comment: Exactly. Ofcourse this webserver has to NOT behind a NAT (or at least a NAT you have config privileges on)

Comment: Do you know of any such tool/open source software through which I can build up my application ?